# Slow SATA I/O after kernel oops (SuperMicro X11SBA-LN4F)

Tags: linux, sata, kernel, ahci, irq

I am in the process of replacing my (Gentoo) Linux router with a new one built using a SuperMicro X11SBA-LN4F.

I used my existing Gentoo Linux router's configs as a starting point (including the kernel config) and after I finished the system install and booted the new kernel, I noticed that anything that touched the SSD was unbearably slow (executing binaries before they are in disk cache, grub-mkconfig, trying to compile the kernel, etc).

When I reboot into my install media and chroot into the install, everything is fine though; this leads me to believe the I/O issues are caused by something that is different about the install media kernel and the system kernel.

I noticed while booted into the system kernel that there was a kernel oops in dmesg that did not appear when I boot from the install media:

```
[   14.325720] irq 19: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)
[   14.325728] CPU: 2 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/2 Not tainted 4.19.23-gentoo #3
[   14.325731] Hardware name: Supermicro SYS-E200-9B/X11SBA-LN4F, BIOS 1.1a 01/23/2018
[   14.325733] Call Trace:
[   14.325742]  <IRQ>
[   14.325755]  dump_stack+0x5a/0x6f
[   14.325766]  __report_bad_irq+0x32/0xa9
[   14.325776]  note_interrupt+0x1cb/0x219
[   14.325786]  handle_irq_event_percpu+0x4d/0x6c
[   14.325793]  handle_irq_event+0x30/0x4e
[   14.325797]  handle_fasteoi_irq+0x7a/0xdf
[   14.325803]  handle_irq+0x19/0x1c
[   14.325810]  do_IRQ+0x3b/0xae
[   14.325819]  common_interrupt+0xf/0xf
[   14.325825]  </IRQ>
[   14.325834] RIP: 0010:cpuidle_enter_state+0x12b/0x17d
[   14.325841] Code: ff 45 84 ff 74 1d 9c 58 0f 1f 44 00 00 0f ba e0 09 73 09 0f 0b fa 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 31 ff e8 0a a4 c6 ff fb 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 <48> 89 d8 b9 e8 03 00 00 4c 29 e8 48 99 48 f7 f9 ba ff ff ff 7f 48
[   14.325844] RSP: 0018:ffff947af50dfea8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffffde
[   14.325850] RAX: ffff947af551f1c0 RBX: 0000000355e105c5 RCX: 000000000000001f
[   14.325853] RDX: 0000000355e105c5 RSI: 0000000050000000 RDI: 0000000000000000
[   14.325856] RBP: ffff947af5527070 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 000000000001ea80
[   14.325858] R10: ffff947af50dfe88 R11: 00000011bcaf990c R12: 0000000000000001
[   14.325861] R13: 0000000355e0df64 R14: ffffffff9f05c538 R15: 0000000000000000
[   14.325869]  ? cpuidle_enter_state+0x102/0x17d
[   14.325874]  do_idle+0x191/0x214
[   14.325883]  cpu_startup_entry+0x6b/0x6d
[   14.325890]  start_secondary+0x18f/0x1ab
[   14.325897]  secondary_startup_64+0xa4/0xb0
[   14.325902] handlers:
[   14.325911] [<00000000f3c0e1a3>] ahci_single_level_irq_intr
[   14.325915] Disabling IRQ #19
```

This appears to be some sort of failure in the AHCI subsystem, presumably related to controlling the Intel SATA chipset on the X11SBA-LN4F board. I spent some time looking at the kernel config (and tried enabling/disabling various AHCI/libata bits). I also tried adding "irqpoll" to the kernel boot arguments without any success. At this point I'm stuck; Google hasn't turned up anything useful for IRQ conflicts with ahci_single_level_irq_intr and I'm not enough of a kernel wizard to know where to look now.

[Kernel Config](https://pastebin.com/mufMTqXa)

[lspci](https://pastebin.com/G6hihzF7)

[dmesg](https://pastebin.com/2914uwVP)

Any insights would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm unsure what's causing that - maybe drop by #gentoo on freenode, someone might recognise the issue.